# Which verb should be used with "(college) course"?

Tags: phrases

Which verb should be used with "(college) course"?

The students are *attending* a course but what is the lecturer doing? "Giving" and...?

Sincerely,
N.G.

Comment: The professor is (lecturing,teaching, delivering, haranguing) the course.

Answer (score 1):

In your case of the students are attending the course.
On the other hand, the professor is...

(According to [**Thesaurus.com**)](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lecture?s=t)

> -Delivering
>
> -Haranguing
>
> **noun**
>
> 1. a scolding or a long or intense verbal attack; diatribe.
> 2. a long, passionate, and vehement speech, especially one delivered before a public gathering.
>
> -lecturing
>
> -teaching

Answer (score 1):

> but what is the lecturer doing?

He is **presenting** the course.

An alternative is **delivering**, but it's not as good, imho.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about [collocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation).

According to [this excellent resource on collocations](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/course), the noun "course" collocates with the verbs **teach**, **offer**, and **run** from the perspective of a professor.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***conduct***. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conducting+a+lecture%2Cconducting+a+course&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconducting%20a%20lecture%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconducting%20a%20course%3B%2Cc0)

> :  to lead from a position of command : *conduct a siege; conduct a
>   class* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conduct)